# MIssingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Emp"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've tried different solutions available on stack overflow but couldn't resolve this problem.

Here is my code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        lowercase:true
    }
});
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
//parameters are model name,schema,collection name
var Emp = mongoose.model('Emp','schema','users');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a string in the second parameter of the model method and it requires a Schema.

This solves your problem:

```
var Emp = mongoose.model('Emp',schema,'users');
```

These are the parameter types you must use:

```
name         String   model name

schema       Schema

collection   String   name (optional, induced from the model name)

skipInit    Boolean whether to skip initialization (defaults to false)
```

more information here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model